# Are Boost's unordered containers Thread-safe for reading?

Tags: c++, multithreading

For example, for MSVC, [read-only is thread-safe on containers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c9ceah3b%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Is boost similarly thread-safe for read-only?

**Update:**
i.e. Can we expect `const' methods to guarantee no memory corruption for multi-threaded use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upcoming standard defines the thread safety of all standard
containers, and I would be very surprised if the boost
implementations didn't meet this guarantee.  In particular, you
should be able to read from any instance of the container from
any thread, as long as no thread is modifying the container.

Answer (score 1):

Typically read operations are thread-safe. I would expect any class implementing a read-only operation (or more generally, a `const` function) to explicitly call out the fact that is is *not* thread safe.

That said, I don't see any thread safety guarantees anywhere.

Comment: Why did you say 'Typically'? I thought read-only containers were *always* thread safe. (ie: If there's no modification to the container elements)

Comment: @Nav: Certainly that is something you would intuitively expect. However, there's nothing stopping a class from having a `const` function (I take it for granted that with no guarantees and no `const`ness, thread safety is out the window) that modifies `mutable` members of the class in a thread-unsafe manner. I wouldn't do it, but it's not guaranteed.

Comment: @Nav I think Jon's point is that for a class type, const means
exactly what the programmer decided that it should mean.
A const member function can access objects with static lifetime,
modify things through pointers, mutable variables, or even cast
away const.  All of which could make it require synchronization.
Typically, however, I would expect a library to contain some
sort of generic guarantee for const functions, with the caveat
"unless otherwise stated".

Comment: Updated the question, the initial wording may not have been clear about read-only.